# refer external url in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wanted to build an angular2 component which can render a external website under my current application page layout, something similar to using IFrame in normal Javascript/JQuery coding.

Please find the sample code below, wherein the internal routing happens when the user clicks on Dashboard1 or Report1 link in the html tag "". 
Sameway when the user clicks on the ExternalLink link, then within the "" specified, the external website should be rendered.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp-menu',
    templateUrl: './Menu.html',
    directives: [menutopbar, leftmenu, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/Dashboard1', name: 'ComponentOne', component: ComponentOne },
        { path: '/Report1', name: 'ReportOne', component: ReportOne },
        { path: '/ExternalLink', name: 'ExternalLink', component: ExternalLink}
])
```

If anyone have idea about how to refer the external website within the current application html page layout, then please share the details

Comment: Why dont you use just 'a' tag with your url in it? <a [href]='<dashboard-variable>'>DashBoard</a> | dashboard-variable = '<my-url>';

Comment: You can route to a component that contains an `<iframe>` that shows that page.

Comment: @Som, If I use 'a' tag then it would be a normal redirection to the specified link/url i.e. the current site would no longer exists (unloaded) and would be replaced with the specified URL. But I don't want to redirect the entire page, instead the external site should be loaded under my website layout within the working space.